# How to target GKE nodes with SSDs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to use `nodeSelectorTerms` to target scheduling of some pods on Nodes with persistent SSD disks. I've created manually a pool with SSDs but I don't see any special labels regarding type of a disk that nodes in this pool use.

I can try to use `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool` label but this looks like a workaround. Plus I'd like to start using [node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) so these pools can be created dynamically with dynamic names.

Answer (score 0):

The `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool` label will contain the name that you have given the node pool, so as you discovered it can be used to [steer your workloads](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/).

If you don't want to rely on that GKE-specific label or you don't think the names of your node pools will be knowable a priori you can [use the GKE API to set a specific label on a node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig).

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this option in the second paragraph of my original question. The issue with `cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool` is that it won't work with [node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning).